# unix tr find and replace

Tags: unix, sed, awk, tr

This is the command I'm using on a standard web page I `wget` from a web site.

```
tr '<' '\n<' < index.html
```

however it giving me newlines, but not adding the left broket in again.
e.g.

```
 echo "<hello><world>" | tr '<' '\n<'
```

returns

```
 (blank line which is fine)
 hello>
 world>
```

instead of

```
 (blank line or not)
 <hello>
 <world>
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 33):

That's because `tr` only does character-for-character substitution (or deletion).

Try `sed` instead.

```
echo '<hello><world>' | sed -e 's/</\n&/g'
```

Or `awk`.

```
echo '<hello><world>' | awk '{gsub(/</,"\n<",$0)}1'
```

Or `perl`.

```
echo '<hello><world>' | perl -pe 's/</\n</g'
```

Or `ruby`.

```
echo '<hello><world>' | ruby -pe '$_.gsub!(/</,"\n<")'
```

Or `python`.

```
echo '<hello><world>' \
| python -c 'for l in __import__("fileinput").input():print l.replace("<","\n<")'
```

Comment: I tried that but I get n<hello>n<world>. I don't know what the sed newline character is

Comment: @Kamran224 This works for me but try: echo -e '<hello><world>' | sed -e 's/</\n&/g'

Comment: @Kamran224 `\n` is a GNU sed extension.  What system are you on?

Comment: @ephemient SunOS (afs system on my campus)

Comment: On SunOS you will have to put the new line manually. In substitution field, hit `enter` and continue with your replacement stuff. For `tab` you will have to manually hit spaces (8 times) or whatever is the default `tab` limit on your machine.

Comment: @ephemient You didnt give `c++` implementation of it!! :P +1

Comment: @Jaypal A string of 8 spaces does not equal a tab; you need a literal tab character. The 8-space thing is about tab stops, not tabs.

Comment: Use `perl` when you are on an unspecified Unix machine. Using `sed` or `tr` on those machines can reveal they don't support expected features.

Answer (score 3):

If you have GNU `grep`, this may work for you:

```
grep -Po '<.*?>[^<]*' index.html
```

which should pass through all of the HTML, but each tag should start at the beginning of the line with possible non-tag text following on the same line.

If you want nothing but tags:

```
grep -Po '<.*?>' index.html
```

You should know, however, that it's [not a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/26428) to parse HTML with regexes.

Answer (score 3):

The order of where you put your newline is important.  Also you can escape the "<".

```
`tr '<' '<\n' < index.html`
```

works as well.

Answer (score 2):

Does this work for you?

```
awk -F"><" -v OFS=">\n<" '{print $1,$2}'

[jaypal:~/Temp] echo "<hello><world>" | awk -F"><" -v OFS=">\n<" '{$1=$1}1';
<hello>
<world>
```

You can put a regex / / (lines you want this to happen for) in front of the `awk` `{}` action.

Comment: `'{$1=$1}1'` is shorter and will work if there is more than `><` on a line.

Comment: This would replace fewer of the `<` characters than in the question.