# Linux convert Comma delimited file to pipe

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk

I have file in linux with comma delimited and string fields in double quotations ", I need to convert them to pipe delimiter please share your inputs.

Example:

Input:

```
"2017-09-30","ACBD,TVF","01234",NULL,18,NULL,"686091802","BANK OF ABCD, LIMITED, THE",790456
```

Output:

```
2017-09-30|ACBD,TVF|01234|NULL|18|NULL|686091802|BANK OF ABCD, LIMITED, THE|790456
```

Thanks In advance...

Thanks,

Comment: Probably belongs on superuser. See "tr" https://ss64.com/bash/tr.html  or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8349771/unix-tr-find-and-replace

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unix tr find and replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8349771/unix-tr-find-and-replace)

Comment: You could use sed .

Comment: @MartinBeckett: This is not simple find & replace because OP wants to keep commas as is within quotes.

Comment: sed and tr will replace all  "," but we have commas in between  string eg: ,"BANK OF ABCD, LIMITED, THE", ..it should be |BANK OF ABCD, LIMITED, THE| .. Please check input and output stings

Comment: @user2601350: Why is your output not showing double quotes around some field values as in input?

Comment: @anubhava, probably because none of the fields now contain the separator, quotes are not strictly required.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using `gnu awk` using `FPAT` variable:

```
awk -v OFS='|' -v FPAT='"[^"]*"|[^,]*' '{
   for (h=1; h<=NF; h++) printf "%s%s", $h, (h < NF ? OFS : ORS)
}' file

"2017-09-30"|"ACBD,TVF"|"01234"|NULL|18|NULL|"686091802"|"BANK OF ABCD, LIMITED, THE"|790456
```

[Working Code Demo](https://ideone.com/43tpf4)

Comment: Thanks for the details but I am getting following output

Comment: "2017-09-30","ACBD,TVF","01234",NULL,18,NULL,"686091802","BANK|OF|ABCD,|LIMITED,|THE",790456

Comment: Are you sure you have gnu awk in your system? Check with `awk --version` command.

Answer (score 1):

You would be well-served to use a proper CSV parser. Here's a Ruby example:

```
ruby -rcsv -e '
  f = ARGV.shift
  csv_out = CSV.new $stdout, :col_sep => "|"
  CSV.foreach(f) {|row| csv_out << row}
' file.csv
```

outputs

```
2017-09-30|ACBD,TVF|01234|NULL|18|NULL|686091802|BANK OF ABCD, LIMITED, THE|790456
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest probably to use sed

`PIPE_SEP_STR=$(echo $COMMA |sed -e 's/,/|/g')`

where COMMA is the variable which contains your comma seperated string

Comment: that will substitute commas inside quoted strings, which is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{sub(/"/,"")gsub(/",|,"|","/,"|")sub(/,18,/,"|18|")}1' file

2017-09-30|ACBD,TVF|01234|NULL|18|NULL|686091802|BANK OF ABCD, LIMITED, THE|790456
```